# MPI Write taking too much memory at the master node

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have a DNS (Direct Numerical Simulations) code that has to handle large amounts of data. While running the code, the code is able to read from a file using the MPI_File_read_all, but after a few iterations, when I want to write out the data using MPI_File_write_all I get a memory error  (signal 9). When I used Valgrind to memory profile, I see that the master node uses more memory than the rest of the nodes, even though there are no data operations that are exclusive to the master node.

This is the read subroutine

```
      subroutine read3DField(filename,vars)
          ! Read binary data file using parallel MPI-IO
          use commons
          include 'sphere.cmn'
          character(len=8), intent(in) :: filename          ! File name
          integer :: ierr
          real vars(nxm:nxp,nym:nyp,nzm:nzp,ns+6)
          type(MPI_File) :: fh
          type(MPI_Status) :: status
          integer(kind=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: disp
            write (*, *) 'Entered read', cartcoord(1)
          call MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, filename, &
                             MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, fh, ierr)
            write (*, *) 'File opened by ', id
                             write(*,*) ierr
          disp = 0
          call MPI_File_set_view(fh, disp, MPI_dp, type_global, &
                                 'native', MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
            write (*, *) 'view set', id
                                 write(*,*) ierr
          call MPI_File_read_all(fh, vars, 1, type_local, status, ierr)
            write (*, *) 'read data', id
          write(*,*) ierr
          call MPI_File_close(fh, ierr)
          write(*,*) ierr
      end subroutine read3DField
```

this is the write subroutine

```
subroutine write3DField(filename,vars)
          ! Write binary data file using parallel MPI-IO
          use commons
          character(len=8), intent(in) :: filename         ! File name
          integer :: ierr
          ! Array to write
          real vars(nxm:nxp,nym:nyp,nzm:nzp,ns+6)
          type(MPI_File) :: fh
          type(MPI_Status) :: status
          integer(kind=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: disp

          call MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, filename, &
                             IOR(MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_MODE_CREATE), MPI_INFO_NULL, fh, ierr)
          disp = 0
          call MPI_File_set_view(fh, disp, MPI_dp, type_global, &
                                 'native', MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
          call MPI_File_write_all(fh, vars, 1, type_local, status, ierr)
          call MPI_File_close(fh, ierr)

end subroutine write3DField
```

type_global and type_local are MPI data types that are initialized previously with appropriate offsets and committed using MPI_commit.

My question is where is this "excess" memory coming from and how to remove it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Without a complete code demonstrating the problem it is very difficult to say anything - I'm guessing you want to get rid of the "memory error". All I can ask at the moment is whether you have run it with all run time checks turned on, `-fcheck=all` for gfortran

Comment: `-fcheck=all` did not return any errors or warnings during runtime. @IanBush how would I create a code demonstration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is the canonical link, but as it's your code that I haven't seen you are the expert at including what is needed, and striping out what is not

Comment: Unless you are running on a Lustre filesystem, you can try two flavors of MPI (one MPICH based vs one Open MPI based) and compare the behavior. That will give you whether the leak is in your code or the MPI library.

Comment: I can imagine that `MPI_Write_all` funnels all its data through process zero. Does your MPI have a mechanism to give process zero a node by itserlf, and let other processes share a node? Are there environment variables to control which processes are doing the writing? This is specific to the MPI implementation.

Comment: On Lustre systems, I think that the standard behaviour is to assign one "aggregator" node per stripe - large files are stored across multiple physical disk units (OSTs) with one stripe per OST - and each aggregator node is responsible for IO to its disk. I think only one rank per aggregator actually writes. For an unstriped file I guess this means that all IO goes via rank 0. However, it should really throttle the memory usage and write out in appropriately sized chunks. The @VictorEijkhout suggestion is very good - try and assign rank 0 to its own node.

Comment: It would be useful to know what kinds of data sizes we're talking about: GiBs, TiBs, ... ?

To clarify me previous comment - I mean that the MPI-IO library internally assigns an "aggregator" per stripe.

Comment: @DavidHenty my input file is around 70GB, but during runtime additional variables are needed. Currently my per node maximum RSS is 57GB when I run with 1452 cores across 178 nodes. But for now, using MPICH over OpenMPI has solved the issue. But I have no clue why.